# Density of absolute continuous measure wrt Lebesgue

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I read the following theorem in my lecture material stating as follows: For any probability measure $\mu$ on $(\mathbf{R},\,\mathcal{B})$ with a density function $f(x)$, the following condition holds for almost all $x$
$$\lim_{h\downarrow 0}\frac{1}{2h}\mu(\{x-h,\,x+h\})=f(x). $$

My question is, by stating a measure 'with a density', does that mean $\mu\ll Leb$, and $\mu$ does not have singular or discrete part? Besides, what is the name of above theorem, where can I find the proof of it?

Comment: I can only really guess, but: I would also assume that it means that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure such that

Comment: Thanks! But regarding the formula for calculating the density, any clue for its proof?

Comment: In any case, it will be useful to write the LHS as an integral of $f$ w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure. You could then argue using a link between Lebesgue integration and Riemann integration and using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, but that seems a bit too restrictive. Give me a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure. This implies the existence of a measurable and Lebesgue integrable function $f$ such that
\begin{align*}
\mu(-\infty,x]
=
\int_{-\infty}^x f(y) \, \mathrm{d}y.
\end{align*}
This shows that the map $F(x) = \mu(-\infty,x]$ is absolutely continuous. (The classic link between probability densities and Radon-Nikodym derivatives.) In particular, $F$ is almost everywhere differentiable with derivative $f$. (I suppose this result is known to you. Otherwise see Royden's or Rudin's.) Can you take it from here?

Comment: If I understand correctly, shouldn't it be $\lim_{h\downarrow 0}\frac{1}{2h}\mu((x-h,\,x+h])=f(x) $ rather than $\lim_{h\downarrow 0}\frac{1}{2h}\mu(\{x-h,\,x+h\})=f(x)$?

Comment: The set $\{x-h\}$ is a Lebesgue null-set and hence also a $\mu$ null-set. Thus the LHS's are identical. But anyway, I would prefer the first expression (it has natural connotations to how we define the Lebesgue measure on sets $(a,b]$).

Comment: @Furrer You are absolutely right. $\mu (\{x-h,x+h\})=0$ so the formula is wrong.

Comment: When lychtalent writes $\{x-h,x+h\}$, I think he means the closed set which I denote $[x-h,x+h]$, so the formula is right. For a singleton $x$ I write $\{x\}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Just to make sure I understand correctly, since $\mu(\{x-h,x+h\})=0$, so $\lim_{h\downarrow 0}\frac{1}{2h}\mu(\{x-h,\,x+h\})=0\neq f(x)$. Instead, it should be $\lim_{h\downarrow 0}\frac{1}{2h}\mu((x-h,\,x+h])=f(x)$, am I correct?

Comment: You are right. Let me also point out that when $\mu << m$ it does not matter whether the interval from $x-h$ to $x+h$ includes the end points  or not. It can be open, closed or half open.

Comment: I interpret $\{x-h, x+h\}$ as a set of two points, not closed interval. I don't know what the author mean. If it means as I interpreted, that would make the formula wrong. Other than the confusion caused by the notion, I think I've got the answer.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. Anyhow, this is weird notation by the author: but the intention is clear. Do you want to write up the answer here for future people passing by?